# React redux atomic design - where redux comes to play?

Tags: reactjs, redux, containers, atomic

In my opinion (which may be of course wrong and that's why I'm posting this question) atomic-design architecture and redux architecture is hard to connect. Don't get me wrong - just follow me.

Atomic design says that all components (except Pages) should not access the main app store and I agree with that. However, they say that only "Pages" elements can be connected to the store (in redux case scenario - having **mapStateToProps**). And this is already a problem, because while having a List component that consist of Item molecules - its better to have a connect function in **single** Item component and get the single entity from store using `props.id`.
Why it's better in real apps? Because it helps with performance. What atomic design suggest to do here? Get large collection from store at "Page" level and pass it down to the template->organism->(finally)molecule. What I see here - a lot of unnecessary re-rendering occurrences caused by mapStateToProps function. For more details, see this post:
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1751

I'm would like to solve this problem and my solution is described here:

Container components (those with connect func) can also be reusable, because mapStateToProps function can access different source of store, using the second argument "ownProps". Why not create container components at molecule level? This also solves "prop-drilling" problem.
Or, if container component at molecule level isn't good idea - maybe then compose containers on "organisms" level?
I really don't know which way is right, so could you please help me with answering the question - where the redux stuff should enter? There is no much articles about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A comment related only to List performance. I'm not sure that connecting items to the store is a good idea, I would better preserve the level of abstraction. Anyway, did you consider using Virtualized lists, an example of a great library for this is react-window. With this you can for example, render only the items visible at the screen instead of rendering all at once.

Comment: Sorry to fall in the category of "did you try X library", just saying that this might not be an atomic design problem, but might want to find another way of solving the List performance. Also read on the rendering cons of passing a second argument ownProps to mapStateToProps at the React Redux documentarion.